# Check if text content is an iFrame or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have a textarea input inside an MVC form, this input must be filled in with a video integration code (iframe) from youtube, vimeo etc...
Before submitting the form I need to check (in js or jquery) if the textarea value is an iframe or not ? is it possible to do it ? any suggestions ? thanks

Comment: A textarea is just text/string - it doesn't contain "an iframe" - it might contain the HTML for an iframe, which is likely what you want to check.  You could use an regex or you could use jquery to parse the text as HTML and then check it that way.

Comment: You can use: `document.getElementById('iframe-input').value.toLowerCase().indexOf('iframe')`